# cron /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Bad fd number

Tags: windows, ubuntu, netbeans, cron

Помогите решить проблему пожалуйста.

Работаю на Windows 10.

Файлы и изменения посылаю на сервер с помощью GIT.

Ошибку приселают мне когда пытаются завести crontab файл.

crontab

```
MAILTO="real@email.com"
*/5 * * * *   cd ~/cap/dir/current && php -f ./c2d/index.php.php > /dev/null 2>&1
# Пробел , либо #
```

Ошибка на емайл:

```
Cron <xxx@xxx> cd ~/cap/dir/current && php -f ./c2d/index.php.php > /dev/null 2>&1
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Bad fd number
```

Спрашивал в чем проблема, говорят:

> ты сохранил файл в виндовом формате. Винда дописаа досовские переводы
>   строк. Пока не уберёшь их, ничего не будет работать.

Если эта ошибка решается на моей (development) стороне , то как бы я не пытался ее иcправит все в пустую .

Может кто сталкивался с подобным ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас доступ только к кронтабу на этом сервере, то сделайте так:

```
MAILTO="real@email.com"
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/5 * * * *   cd ~/cap/dir/current && php -f ./c2d/index.php.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```